# Is there any chance to update an extremely old rmpi system to a specific version?

Tags: pi-2

I have a software image file that is used for running system on raspberry pi model B and ~50 microcomputers that are running on it right now. I need to somehow update this old pile of rust to a specific version, `Linux rmpi 5.10.103-v7+` or similar. `uname -a` gives me this `Linux rmpi 3.18.11+ #781 PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:02:18 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux`. `Apt-get update` do nothing since all the packages are missing and `--fix-missing` not solving the problem.

UPD:
I also tried to change wheezy to jessie in `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`. No use. Also tried the script described and supplied in the RPi forum post [*"Building the Raspberry Pi OS Kernel : Made Easy"*](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=343387&sid=a85e5aee66b55bfac80873801ab0102f) but it fails with strange reason - can't find a branch which definitely is present on repo.

Comment: @Milliways well just because. We have newer version of our software but it only applicable to a newer version of kernel...

Comment: When you say the "build kernel" script fails because it can't find a branch - is this branch that it cannot find located in the raspberrypi.com repository - or in the linux kernel repository?  In either case, I'd suggest that you follow up with the author of that post for clarification; IMO, RonR is bright, dedicated and x-helpful!

Comment: @Seamus the link in script leading to `https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux` and all the branches I have tried are present in repo. Later I came to conclusion that the problem is with some ca certificates and I can not update them bc of how old the system is, so its no use... Anyway thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading your question, and the comments already made, I'm not sure I have a perfectly clear picture of what you're trying to do. I offer this based on my best guess of your objectives:

It seems that you've got a model B RPi, it's got a very broken old version of the OS installed, and you want to upgrade your system *without* losing all the data on your old system.

First, your options for upgrading using `apt` - or `apt-get` - are likely ***non-existent***. There are a couple of reasons for this situation:

1. for **most** OS version upgrades, the RPi.com crowd does not support a "manual" upgrade; i.e. an upgrade accomplished by `apt` with `apt-get dist-upgrade` and such is just not supported by RPi.com.
2. AFAIK, older distributions such as `jessie` are not maintained, and may not even be available any longer. However, you're welcome to peruse the [RPi sources](http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/) (from `/etc/apt/sources.list`) if you like (you *may* find something?). Also, *"skipping"* versions (e.g. `wheezy` to `buster` or `bullseye`) becomes even more problematic when doing *manual* upgrades.

Instead, the RPi.com crowd encourages users to upgrade via fresh installation. So I won't say the *manual* upgrade **can't** be done, but I will say that it might be a struggle even for someone with good skills & background. In my opinion, the course of action that's most likely to succeed for upgrading is as follows:

1. get a new SD card,
2. download a copy of the ["Raspberry Pi Imager" (aka "installer")](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/) to your Windows or Mac
3. download a current [Raspberry Pi OS Lite image file](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/), and
4. install the new image file on the new SD card

***Definitely*** keep the old SD card as there may be scripts and other information peculiar to whatever functions your "~50" Rpi performed. Once you get a new OS installed, you can `mount` an old SD card and copy whatever files you need.

###### EDIT (in response to OP's comment, *"no way to do it without a new SD card for every Rpi"*):

This is ***not*** to say that you must have a new SD card for every Pi. If the old SD cards are still functional, they can simply be ***re-written***, and ***re-used***. What I ***should have said*** was that ***IF*** the existing SD card(s) had/have data on them that you don't want to lose, then you should get a copy of that data ***before*** re-writing them.

IOW, if all of the SD cards are identical, you may need only to replace one of them. And possibly not even one - if you want to ***copy everything*** that's on the SD card, and save it to a file(s).

The whole idea with this SD card comment was to **preserve any unique data** that may be stored on the card(s). But if there's not - or if you simply don't need it - then by all means, re-write as many cards as you can.

Comment: OK seems like no way to do it without a new SD card for every Rpi. Thanks for the detailed response

Comment: @SomeRandomDude111: Uh... No - I didn't say a new SD card for every Pi. Pls see the edit to my answer for clarification.

Comment: Note that SD cards have a short life, limited number of write cycles.  So you will eventually need to get a new card for every pi anyway...and doing a massive number of writes to update the OS could add enough wear that some fraction of them may fail right then.

Comment: Depends on the quality of the sd cards and the type of activity you are doing on the pi's.  Out of maybe 20 cards, I've worn out 2 in 5 years, but I'm trying to be gentle to them.  I bet most of them are less than 0.3 DWPD, meaning if you wrote every block every day it'd wear out in around 100 days.  But that's MTBF not max, so some will fail sooner.  Obviously larger (overprovisioned) cards will last longer assuming wear leveling.

Comment: @Seamus in my case it is definitely easier to write a whole bunch of new SDs and send them across country to replace old ones than re-write existing ones... Because they have been working for quite a while already, a few years. And no one knows when exactly old SD will die, so this is a safer option too